# How do I tell Castle Inversion of Control that I want a new instance of a singleton object without restarting the app?

Tags: inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, ioc-container

At a certain point, during the running of my app, I want Castle.Windsor to release everything cached in memory. Is this impossible for a singleton object?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? if you need to reinstantiate a singleton then it's not really a singleton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to get around an unrelated problem by doing this. It is not the solution. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want a singleton, [you want a Custom LifeStyle](http://www.castleproject.org/container/documentation/v21/usersguide/lifestyles.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use nested container for that, register singleton in the nested container and it will get released. But why are you doing it in the first place?